# Page not showing correctly on chrome/safari browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web

I am having a problem with a website that I have made.
Whenever i try to open it in Chrome in a low resolution device, the nav bar remains like a 1920x1080 pc, and the loading circle that pop ups when you enter the site is not centered in either chrome or safari.
I Know I am messing up with the CSS but cant figure out how.
[My site](http://hotelbelsur.com.ar/).
Thanks

Comment: Post your source code, not a link to the website, because 1) this question becomes useless to everyone else once the bug is fixed, 2) for those of us at work, some websites (such as yours) are blocked.

Comment: It seems like may be due to your own CSS div { display : block } it is not getting hidden while it is being loaded on the small devices.